# Config option to disable update capability per environment

Tags: config, multi-environment, updating

In our workflow, we run a shared development server. Each developer develops locally but points to the development database. All Craft software updates need to happen while in the local environment and then changes need to immediately be committed to the git repo otherwise things could get really screwed up.

I would the option to disable the update capability using a multi-environment config setting so we could prevent anyone from running those updates on the shared development server.

I know we could set up user permissions to lock this down, but I think it would be much handier to be able to do that at the config level.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the '[allowAutoUpdates](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#allowAutoUpdates)' config option combined with [multi-environment configs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs).

Comment: FML - Sorry guys.

Comment: It's all good, @JacobGraf :)